# Multiple Boost::ASIO async_send_to in one go

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp, asio

I want to increase the throughput of my udp gameserver which uses Boost ASIO.
Right now, everytime i need to send a packet, i am putting it in a queue, then checking if there is a pending async_send_to operation, if yes, do nothing, if not, call async_send_to.
Then i wait for the write handler to be called and then call async_send_to for the next packet in queue, if any.

The documentation says that it is the way to do it "for TCP socket", but there is NOTHING on the whole internet about UDP socket.
Try it, search it on stackoverflow, you will see nobody talks about this, and for the 2 questions you will find, the question is left ignored by users.

Why is it kept a secret?
And for the 1million dollar question, can i safely call async_send_to multiple time in a row WITHOUT waiting for the write handler to be called?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This logic is meaningless for the UDP protocol since it doesn't need to block send operation. A datagram is either delivered or lost. UDP don't have to store it in the output buffer and resend indefinitely many times until it get ACK packet.

Comment: So to make sure, am i able to call all async_send_to in a row, without waiting for write handler to be called, with of course keeping the buffer valid until handler called?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot safely call `async_send_to` multiple times in a row WITHOUT waiting for the write handler to be called. See [Asynchronous IO with Boost.Asio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwOv_tw2eA4) to see precisely why.

However, `asio` supports [scatter gather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectored_I/O) and so you can call `async_send_to` with multiple buffers, e.g.:

```
typedef std::deque<boost::asio::const_buffer> ConstBuffers;

std::string msg_1("Blah");
...
std::string msg_n("Blah");

ConstBuffers buffers;
buffers.push_back(msg_1);
...
buffers.push_back(msg_n);

socket_.async_send_to(buffers, tx_endpoint_, write_handler);
```

So you could increase your throughput by `double buffering` your message queue and using gathered writes...

Comment: Does scatter gather send all buffers as a single datagram?

Comment: That depends on how much data you need to transfer, how big is your ethernet frame, etc. but it will try to do its best to fit it in as few datagrams as possible.

Comment: A UDP datagram larger than the interface MTU can be split into multiple fragments at the IP layer.  These fragments are then reassembled before the complete datagram is presented to the application, e.g. via `recvfrom()`.  The framing of data into datagrams is precisely specified when they are sent and in the socket API, and is often a critical part of a protocol using UDP.   The buffers can not be combined into multiple UDP datagrams in some unknown way.